# iOS - network connection when app is in background when notification arrives

Tags: ios, background-fetch

I have a requirement where I need to make a network connection when a new push notification arrives while app is in background.

Is it possible to do so? Some hook?

Right now, I make the connection when notification is swiped to open the app. However, it delays when the user sees the new data.

Any other way of getting data faster from server triggered by a new push notification?

Comment: Try to use silent push notifications.

Comment: Silent push notifs will not help me due to its rate limiting attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [didReceiveRemoteNotification...](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) method if you are using apns or [didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload](https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/1614492-pushregistry?language=objc) if you are using pushkit.

You need to enabled the remote notifications background mode or voip for pushkit.